# Any tricks for checking if a ethernet cable is in use?

Tags: cable

Faced with bundles of white cat5 in the attic, any suggestions for non-intrusive checks to determine which ones are in use?

Thanks,
Kent

Comment: Is this for a professional environment, or a home/personal use environment? 
If the latter your question is off-topic here, but possibly well suited for SuperUser and I can migrate it for you...

Comment: Go to either end of the cable attach a tone generator to unused connection.  Use the probe to identify which cable you attached the tone generator to.  http://www.amazon.com/dp/B000FTADX0/

Comment: If the cables are tightly bundled then you have zero chance. If not bundled, try using a Fluke PRO3000 Tone and Probe Kit 1-3 cm from the cable when the cables are separated by at least twice that distance from each other.

Comment: I'll use my toner if I can access the ends ...

So no one is stripping a bit of jacket, piercing org wires and looking at them with a hand held oscilloscope? Maybe even a DVM looking for ac?

OK, tried slitting the jacket, connecting piercing clips to the org pair, plugged into DVM. Didn't see any ac voltage, but the frequency counting function registered numbers which go away when the cable is unplugged. A ping stream wasn't affected by the presence of the DVM.

So far this appears a viable test. Comments?

Thanks, Kent